# Not able to get anything in selector function from the store

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

[image]

```js
    import { createSelector } from 'reselect';
    import { INITIAL_STATE } from './reducer';
    import _ from "lodash";
    import { has } from 'lodash';

    export const selectWeather = (state) => state.data || {};
    console.log("state", selectWeather)

    export const getCityInfo = () =>
        createSelector(
            selectWeather,

            state => has(state, 'data') ? state.data : '',

        ); ',);
```

this is a function from selector.js trying to get info from store but not able to get it. I think I am not able to reach the state itself.

Comment: How are you accessing the state and calling the selector?  Did you remember to wrap your whole `App` in a `Provider` from redux?  If you can't access the state then the most likely cause is that you are trying to access it from outside of a `Provider`

Comment: Your selector is getting `state.data.data` are you sure you understand how reselect works? If you want to get a city from the data array then maybe [this](https://github.com/amsterdamharu/selectors#parameterized-selector) can help you, but it would be best if selectWeather always returns an array and not sometimes an array and sometimes an object depending if state.data is undefined.